# Compile OpenCv with CUDA support on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, opencv, cuda

I am trying to compile program with OpenCv with CUDA support on linux. I created Makefile:

```
filtry_gpu: filtry_gpu.cu
     nvcc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -I/opt/opencv/include -L/opt/opencv/lib -Xcompiler \-fopenmp -Xcompiler \-Wall -Xlinker \-lgomp filtry_gpu.cu -o filtry_gpu 

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

but I got errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(218): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(225): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(711): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(717): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(964): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(964): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(988): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(988): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1012): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1012): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1060): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1060): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1132): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1181): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1199): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1199): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1229): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1229): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1235): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1235): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1241): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1241): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1247): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1247): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1253): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1253): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1426): error: argument of type "__v2di *" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long *"

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.3.5/include/emmintrin.h(1426): error: argument of type "__v2di" is incompatible with parameter of type "__attribute((vector_size(16))) long"
```

My openCV version is 4.3.7, CUDA 4.0, g++ 4.4

The same program works fine in visual Studio 2012. Is there any way to compile this on linux?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using OpenCV 2.4 version. You can't use OpenCV headers in CUDA code. To use OpenCV in your CUDA project split your file onto two files : `.cpp` and `.cu` and put all CUDA code to `.cu` file and all OpenCV code to `.cpp` file.

Comment: Is there any possiblity to put code in one file? Visual studio allow that ;p

Comment: In master branch you can use OpenCV headers in CUDA code. But master branch is not stable yet.